# Text of מוריד הטל

Tags: minhag, geshem-tal-ruach

Why in the mentioning of God's power to bring dew in the shemoneh esrei do we only say מוריד הטל when during the תפילת טל on פסח we say the whole phrase of משיב הרוח ומוריד הטל?

Comment: Some indeed _do_ say משיב הרוח ומוריד הטל in Shemoneh Esrei. For instance, the Breslov kehillah in Tzefat recites it as it was R' Gedaliah Kenig's custom. See [here](http://breslovcenter.blogspot.com/2012/05/reb-gedaliahs-nusach-for-shemoneh-esreh.html).

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that "morid hatal" is for the summer months and "mashiv haruach umorid hageshem" is for winter, and we say Tefillas Tal in the spring, halfway between the two seasons?

Comment: @ezra indeed in old Israeli Nusach they said the full phrase. That's why it's like that in the poems of Tefillat Tal, because that was composed in old Israel